# BT 4.0 Mouse not pairing with Mac OS Sonoma

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, macbook-pro, macos-sonoma

I'm having trouble pairing my mouse to my new Mac M2 with Mac OS Sonoma.

It was working previously on a Mac M1 with Mac OS Monterey and works fine with all older Mac configurations.

When trying to pair through bluetooth settings, the loader starts animating for a while then stops and nothing happens. I'm supposed to be prompted a dialog to insert the `0000` PIN code but it never shows.

[Device properly listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGAEN.png)

[Pairing attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJhai.png)

After several Google researches, I decide to use the terminal to try the pairing with a different method. I found out that `blueutil` tool was largely used as a CLI tool for bluetooth. But, unfortunately it didn't work.

I tried the pairing option with the usual PIN code (that worked fine with older Macs):

```
~$ blueutil --pair dc-2c-26-1d-0a-f5 0000
Failed to pair "dc-2c-26-1d-0a-f5" with error 0x1f (Unspecified Error)
```

I have tried to [reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) as it was suggested in some forum answers et done this again and I have the same issue.

Comment: Yeah ! Well, that's the solution I want to avoid. But I know that a newer one could work I juste don't want to keep buying new mouses.

Comment: You mouse should work. Granted, BT 4.0 has been superseded but 5.x receivers are still retro-compatible with pretty much anything older except, of course, for the 5.x specific features. Nothing that could be applicable to BT mouse so you can ignore the first comment.